# Issue creating query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, in mySql database, like these :

GROUPS:

```
| IDGroup| IDRat| Type| Category|
| 708    | 354  | 1   | A       |
| 709    | 354  | 1   | C       |
```

Where `IDGroup` is the primary key.

USERS:

```
| IDUser| Name| Surname | IDGroup |
| 1     | John| Doe     | 708     |
| 2     | Mick| Caine   | 708     |
```

Where the primary key is `IDUser`

I want create a query that, **receives as parameter the IDRat** and returns the results like this:

```
| IDGroup| Type| Category | Number_of_Users_in_this_group |
```

where, as the name suggest, the fourth column represents the number of users associated with the group.

For example passing the `IDRat = 354` I want obtain the following result:

```
| IDGroup| Type| Category | Number_of_Users_in_this_group |
| 708    | 1   | A        | 2                             |
| 709    | 1   | C        | 0                             |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query does what you want:

```
SELECT g.IDGroup, g.Type, g.Category, COUNT(u.IDGroup) 
FROM GROUPS g left join
     USERS u
     on g.IDGroup = u.IDGroup 
WHERE IDRat = XXX
GROUP BY g.IDGroup;
```

The `left join` keeps all groups.  The `count()` will return `0` when there is no match.  The `where` clause does the filtering.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IDGroup,Type,Category,COUNT(u.IDGroup) as NoUsers
FROM GROUPS g 
LEFT JOIN USERS u ON g.IDGroup=u.IDGroup 
WHERE IDRat=354 GROUP BY g.IDGroup
```

Comment: it should be `COUNT(u.IDGroup)`

Comment: ... and `LEFT JOIN` , not `INNER`

Comment: @Mihai . . . Three things need improvement in this query.  First, the `group by` goes before the `having` clause.  Second, it uses `where` where you mean `on` (this is acceptable syntax in MySQL but not in any other database).  Third, the `having` clause chooses an *arbitrary* value of `IDRat` for each group.  If you want row filtering *before* aggregation, then the condition needs to be in the `where` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Damn,I`ll go sit in the corner now.

Answer (score 1):

select required column and join these table and group result by IDGroup

```
select IDGroup,Type,Category,COUNT(IDGroup) as Number_of_Users_in_this_group
FROM GROUPS JOIN USERS WHERE GROUPS .IDGroup=USERS .IDGroup 
HAVING IDRat=354 GROUP BY IDGroup
```